# Get ACF Image field from Custom Taxonomy loop/list (woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

Been banging my head for a few hours trying to sort this. Finally got a function together that will list all the terms in a custom taxonomy I created in Woocommerce > Products, which works.

What I want to do:

Get/Display the image for each term next to the title (Created an Image field with ACF for that taxonomy item) and display the description underneath.

I can probs figure out the description part, but having a hard time with getting the image to render.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
//---------Start ACF code
//
// Define taxonomy prefix
// Replace NULL with the name of the taxonomy eg 'category'
$taxonomy_prefix = 'item';

// Define term ID
// Replace NULL with ID of term to be queried eg '123' 
$term_id = NULL;

// Define prefixed term ID
$term_id_prefixed = $taxonomy_prefix .'_'. $term_id;

//----------End ACF Code 

$taxonomy     = 'item';
  $orderby      = 'name';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 0;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id; 
        $image = get_field('image', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
        echo '  <img src="'.the_field( 'image', $term_id ) .'" /> ';
        echo '<a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'item') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a><br />';

        $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
            if($sub_cats) {
                foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                    echo  '<a class="subcat" href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'item') .'">'. $sub_category->name .'</a><br/>';
                }
            }
    }       
}
```

You can see the output here:
https://doorsdev.wpengine.com/individual-flower-essence-descriptions/

When I inspect I can see the  field rendering but a blank src attribute, and with no errors on the page, I'm not sure what to do next.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the $term_id, becuase it tells me to define it, but since I don't want one specific term, I want it for each term that gets pulled into the loop....I'm not sure how to define that.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as shown in the code your $term_id is null. Try replacing `$term_id` with `$category_id`.

Replace this code(EDITED).

```
 $image = get_field('image', 'term_' . $category_id);
 echo '  <img src="'.$image .'" /> ';
```

Reference: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Comment: thanks for the response. When making that replacement, where do I find the category id?

Or perhaps I've mixed up my terminology and made it confusing. 

I created a custom tax called "Ingredients" (registered as "item") - I want to display a list of all the ingredients, which is done and can be seen on the link. Along with that, I want to display the ACF image field I've added there and the description. 

The category ID - where do I find that, assuming it shouldn't be NULL? 
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=item&post_type=product

Usually the url shows it but not in this case

Comment: You have already declared `$category_id = $cat->term_id;`

Comment: Alright so I saw your response as I was editing mine - I replaced $term_id with $category_id in the place you referenced above, but same result. Do I need to change it anywhere else?

Comment: is everything working fine except image?

Comment: Correct. I've only done the title/link right now, I can probably figure out how to include the description, but the image right now just pulls in a blank src based on what I have above. If you need screenshots or any other info to help understand just let me know.

Comment: you have to debug it manually. 1. check the field name and return format is image URL in ACF fields. then 2. check in your loop that you are getting the term_id using echo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249398/discussion-between-zillionera-dev-and-nilssonc).